# Binding html table data with mysql data (DataTables, jEditable, etc.)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

If there is a thread explaining this, please let me know.

I have looked at things like Jeditable and am trying to understand how the mysql id is passed/stored in the html, or just how to do this on my own. Is there some hash table with the html id linked with the mysql id? Is this an inefficient method?

Jeditable requires a php page for the data, so what is the most efficient way to find out what mysql table/row is being represented by the edit? Obviously the data can change so it is not useful, so then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use jqgrid, it has an editable table that loads data either using XML or JSON

Check out their website
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

and here is a demo where you can find how it connects to DB and how you can manipulate or edit your data:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Please tell me if its useful for you!

Comment: That was sort of helpful. It's very clean and I like the functionality.

My concern is whether or not it is a bad idea for the user to be able to see what MySQL row their data is in. Like in the example you sent me, the Inv. # is not editable, because I am assuming it is the primary key. Is that bad for the user to see that? Or is that not really a security risk?

Comment: it might be a security issue, but from my experience i can tell you, only show the user what he/she needs to see, nothing more